# Entity Framework VB.net - Add-Migration New Model not generate database code

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

Hi all and thanks in advance,

I'm having a extrange issue with entity framework with VB.net in VS2017.

I don't know why, but now if I create a new model, when making "Add-Migration" EF don't generate anything. But if I change a previous model, EF generates (and update-database) correctly.

In Migrations configuration I have *AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = True*

I tried to use and old database, update it, and try to make the migration again, reinstall VS, apply some small change in a model and before add the new model, but no one of this works.

Any idea about what could be happening?

Best regards,

**My new Model code:**

```
Imports Pricing.Models
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class TagLink
    Public Property ID As Integer

    <Display(Name:="Nombre")> <Required>
    Public Property Name As String

End Class
```

**Empty migration generated**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Entity.Migrations
Namespace Migrations
    Public Partial Class AddTagLink
        Inherits DbMigration

        Public Overrides Sub Up()
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub Down()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

---

**Previous Model Changed**

```
Imports Pricing.Models
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Public Class Counterparty
    Public Property ID As Integer
    <Display(Name:="Nombre")> <Required>
    Public Property Name As String
    <Display(Name:="Descripción")> <Required>
    Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

**Migration generated**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Entity.Migrations

Namespace Migrations
    Public Partial Class CounterPartiesDescription
        Inherits DbMigration

        Public Overrides Sub Up()
            AddColumn("dbo.Counterparties", "Description", Function(c) c.String(nullable := False))
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub Down()
            DropColumn("dbo.Counterparties", "Description")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Do you add your new class to your context class? Please put all of your context class here.

Comment: No, but thats was the issue, is resolved. thanks a lot! It's been a long time since I used VS and I did not remember that